# Getting data get_posts() and passing it to a function wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, foreach

So, I am figuring out how to send my old orders to mailchimp. Since I cannot really find much info on this I'm testing stuff till I get some reasonable outcome.

```
<?php     
// Get all customer orders
$customer_orders = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
    'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
) );

var_dump($customer_orders); //to see what I'm working with

echo "test";
require_once('../public_html/wp-content/plugins/woochimp/woochimp.php'); 

foreach($customer_orders as $cuord) {
    $order = $cuord->ID; 
    echo ($cuord->post_date);
    echo "<br>";
    on_completed($order); //I'm trying to run this as it should try to send some data to mailchimp.
}
?>
```

When I call the on_completed function it seems to break the foreach loop. What am I doing wrong?

The on_completed function: (from the plugin WooChimp)

```
    /**
     * Subscribe on order completed status and send Ecommerce360 data
     *
     * @access public
     * @param int $order_id
     * @return void
     */
    public function on_completed($order_id)
    {
        // Check if functionality is enabled
        if (!$this->opt['woochimp_enabled']) {
            return;
        }

        // Check if WC order class is available and MailChimp is loaded
        if (class_exists('WC_Order') && $this->load_mailchimp()) {

            // Do we need to subscribe user on completed order or payment?
            $subscribe_on_completed = get_post_meta($order_id, 'woochimp_subscribe_on_completed', true);
            $subscribe_on_payment = get_post_meta($order_id, 'woochimp_subscribe_on_payment', true);

            foreach (array('auto', 'checkbox') as $sets_type) {
                if ($subscribe_on_completed == $sets_type || $subscribe_on_payment == $sets_type) {
                    $this->subscribe_checkout($order_id, $sets_type);
                }
            }

            // Check if we need to send order data or was it already sent
            if (!$this->opt['woochimp_send_order_data'] || self::order_data_sent($order_id)) {
                return;
            }

            // Get args
            $args = $this->prepare_order_data($order_id);

            // Send order data
            try {
                $this->mailchimp->ecomm_order_add($args);
                update_post_meta($order_id, '_woochimp_ecomm_sent', 1);
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->woochimp_log_write($e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can we see the on_completed function please :)

Comment: I have added it to the post but it might get a bit complicated right now. 
The plugin from which this function is, is working seamless. I assume it works, but I could be giving it a wrong value..

Answer (score 0):

What error message text do you see if on_completed($order) function call is placed in try catch block? Example below:

```
try {
    on_completed($order);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Also, please check your web server error_log. Do you see any errors, when your code is executed?

Comment: Please also check your woo commerce log settings. It may be disabled. You should enable it to see for on_completed error exception messages.

Comment: Please, also post your error_log and related settings from phpinfo() function output: error_log, log_errors, error_reporting